# OMG How can I remedy these last 2 issues: concerning: Extraneous Property & Parser Mismatched Metadata: I don't know enough syntax to do this

Tags: facebook-like

I have this last one warning and don't know how to resolve . I have spent about a week and 3 days hacking away reading stuff on this site but I just do not have the background to fix whatever it is these warnings keep me up at night about. I am sorry to bug you guys about this but I don't know the definitions and syntax to make this stuff work right and THANK YOU in advance. Here is the page:

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:page_id'.

Parser Mismatched Metadata: The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only expecting a single value, or property values for a given property being mismatched.

Here are the input properties that were not seen in the parsed result: 'fb:page_id'
Object Properties

fb:admins:  Array of length 1
⍾ 691633904

og:url: http://www.penosoimages.com/
og:type:    website
og:title:   Northern Virginia Photographic Services
og:image:
og:description: Event Coverage and Portrait Photography for Northern Virginia
og:site_name:   Vincent Penoso Photography
og:updated_time:    1352162367
Raw Open Graph Document Information

Meta Tag:   
Meta Tag:   
Meta Tag:   
Meta Tag:   
Meta Tag:   
Meta Tag:   
Meta Tag:   
URLs

Comment: Can someone please give a hint or is this something I need to worry about?